# Powershll help killing a service remotely

Tags: powershell, cmd

When I try to kill a Service using PowerShell on a remote computer it doesn't let me do it, especially when the service is hung, but interesting enough I can do it if I use CMD so what am I doing wrong?
--- Does not work

```
Get-Service -ComputerName XXXXXX -DisplayName 'CrystalService'| Stop-Service
```

or
-- Does not work

```
Get-Service -ComputerName XXXXXX -DisplayName 'CrystalService'| Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Stopped"} | Restart-Service
```

CMD---This works every time!!!!!

```
taskkill /s computername  /im crystalservice.exe /f
```

Comment: Are you sure that the exact display name is `CrystalService`? The examples on [Microsoft Docs on `Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6) show wildcards. Perhaps you should be trying something like `Get-Service -ComputerName XXXXX -DisplayName "*Crystal*" ...` instead.

Comment: I agree with Jeff, you may be referencing the name and not the display name

Comment: Have you tried adding the -Force flag to the Stop-Service command?

Comment: @jeff Well when I run just the first part it does show me that service status. `Get-Service -ComputerName XXXXXX -DisplayName 'CrystalService`

Comment: @RetiredGeek  Yeah I have tried it and it works but when the service is hung I can only kill it using the Command line and not Powershell, so I am wondering is there a reason for that?

Comment: Well, run it with `-name` and see what you get. If you're not getting anything it means it's not there, or the name is incorrect. Shorten the name and add a wildcard `'*crystal*'`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So, is it a service, or a process?

Comment: Your command prompt example shows crystAservice - missing the L and includes .exe  where your powershell examples show crystaLservice

Comment: So, is it a service, or a process?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala it is a service

Comment: @DougMaurer good catch, but that was a typo on my end not the powershell I am running.

Comment: okay so I had the display name and not service name I checked services and found it! Thanks guys